# ignore files in a branch

Tags: git, gitignore

I was working on a new created branch, and I generated some images in that branch. The thing is that i have *.png in my .gitignore file, but git continue to track them. Do you have any idea about how can I ignore the picture files in this branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git will not stop tracking files that are already in your repository. The ignore directive merely prevents it from adding new files automatically. If you want to stop tracking them, you have to explicitly remove them (`git rm --cached`, probably).